# <A>nchor's href being overridden by containing <div>'s onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, event-bubbling

When I click on the following link inside the outer div, I get the `confirm` statement, but after clicking 'OK', nothing happens.

```
HTML:
<div onclick="toggleExerciseDetails($(this),true)" class="clickable">
...
    <a target="_blank" href="http://iPUMPit.local/exercises/delete/275"
        onclick="cancelPropagation(event);return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this exercise?');"
        title="Delete this exercise" class="icon icon_delete"></a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
// cancels propagation of an event to the outer element event
function cancelPropagation(e) {
    if (!e)
        var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Why isn't my click following the url?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you replace the entire onclick with return True does it do what you want? That is all your confirm is doing, which I expect is not your goal.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? You may wan to publish your `toggleExerciseDetails()` method.  And it looks like you're using jquery.

Comment: But let's start at the beginning. Does `toggleExerciseDetails` get executed?

Comment: @MrLister: No, it never gets executed if I click on the link.
@Keeyai: It does nothing if I replace it with `return true;`.
@shanabus: I would, but after realizing that it is not even executed, there is no use.

Comment: OK, and if you take the `<a>` out of said `<div>`, without changing anything else, does it work then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .stopPropagation():

```
$('div.clickable a').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eZr3k/)**.

This will make your link clickable but not allow the event to bubble up to the div, while keeping the div clickable.

Comment: Did you try the jsFiddle? Works there. Maybe you have other code causing a conflict?

Comment: Technically your answer was right, given the above info, so you deserve the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I had another `click` handler on `.icon`s which returned `false`. My bad, guys! Thanks for the help!